# Single-word synonym for "immensely valuable"?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for some (may be rarely know to nonnative English speakers) synonyms for  "immensely valuable" or "extremely valuable".

Answer (score 9):

The word "invaluable" is what you're looking for I think. Definition: beyond calculable or appraisable value.

Answer (score 7):

To quote the well-know credit card ad: [priceless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/priceless).

Answer (score 4):

There are also the terms [*precious*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/precious), which means "of great price; costly; having a high money-value; of great worth; held in high esteem; intrinsically valuable," and [*inestimable*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/inestimable), which means "of immeasurable value or worth; invaluable."